# Search for records with similar tag id

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have a tagging table that looks like this:

```
id  |  product_id | tag_id
---------------------------
1   |           1 |     10
2   |           1 |     12
3   |           2 |     10
4   |           3 |     11
```

I'm creating a search page which take tags as input by user (1 or more) and search the database for records with those tags present.

For example:

- if user entered '10' then with the table above the result would be product_id 1 & 2.

#### EDIT:

- There are 2 user input

  1. Include tag -> search for product with these tags
  2. Exclude tag -> search for products without these tags

So the search query would have to first ignore the exclude tags then search for product with 'include tag'.

#### EDIT 2:

The user can enter 1 or more tag.

---

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fairly simple approach using aggregation and `having`:

```
select tt.product_id
from tagtable tt
group by tt.product_id
having sum(tt.tag_id in ($excludedtags)) = 0 and
       sum(tt.tag_id in ($includedtags)) = #NumberIncludedtags;
```

You need to put in the number of included tags for the second condition.  Also, this assumes that the tags table does not have duplicated rows (if so, this is easily fixed by using `count(distinct)`, but that clutters the query).

Answer (score 1):

Run this SQL query :

```
$includedTags = join(',',$incTagsIdArr);
$excludedTags = join(',',$excTagsIdArr);
$sql = "SELECT product_id FROM $tagTable WHERE tag_id IN ($includedTags) AND tag_id NOT IN ($excludedTags)"
```

where :

- `$incTagsIdArr` is the array of request tag ids by the user
- `$excTagsIdArr` is the array of excluded tag ids by the user
- `$tagTable` is your "tagging" table name

Comment: the problem is that the input can be 1 or more tag and there are 2 input, one to exclude and one to include. I have updated my question

Comment: how efficient is this query when user enter like 10+ tags in each list? like 10 tags to exclude and 10 tags to include?

Comment: Query shown is much like
ls *.jpg | egrep -v 'aa|bb|cc'

Comment: @RémiBecheras: for some reason your solution doesnt remove product_id with tag in $excTagsIdArr. Query I use: SELECT m.id FROM product m INNER JOIN tagging tg ON (m.id = tg.pdt_id) WHERE 1 AND (nme LIKE 'tomo%' OR alt_nme LIKE 'tomo%') AND (tg.tag_id IN (34,20) AND tg.tag_id NOT IN (42)) GROUP BY m.id

Comment: What do you mean by « doesnt remove product_id » ?

Comment: so the query above return records that has tag in $excTagsIdArr. or it returns same set of records as SELECT m.id FROM product m INNER JOIN tagging tg ON (m.id = tg.pdt_id) WHERE 1 AND (nme LIKE 'tomo%' OR alt_nme LIKE 'tomo%') GROUP BY m.id (without the in and not in cond)